# Complex Integration over a Circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Find integral $$\oint \mathrm{d}z \frac{z-7}{z^{23}-1}$$ over the circle of radius 3 centered at origin. I have been trying to do this by Cauchy Integral Formula,but the calculation is coming too long. Please help.

Comment: hmm,  looks like you have 23 simple poles, equally spaced.  There may be some shortcut for adding up the residues....I'm new to residue theory myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral over a circle of radius R with R going to infinity will go to zero and be independent of $R$ so will be zero for $R>7.$ Now the difference between its integral and that of the circle of radius 3 will be determined by the residue at 7.